Swift testing parameterized tests only run on first argument
I've been exploring the new-ish Swift Testing framework and want to take advantage of parameterized tests.
@Test("Test fetch contacts with insufficient permissions", arguments: [
        CNAuthorizationStatus.denied,
        CNAuthorizationStatus.restricted,
        CNAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
    ])
    func fetchContacts_insufficientPermissions(status: CNAuthorizationStatus) throws {
        dependencies.contactStore.currentAuthStatus = status
        
        var receivedPermissionsError = false

        /// Do some work to trigger permissions error.
        
        #expect(receivedPermissionsError == true)
    }

When running the above code, the test only runs once, with the first argument in the array. My understanding is that the test should be executed against each argument and run three times.
Is there something procedurally that my test is missing?

The test looks ok in general so maybe this is something specific for the Contacts framework. Does other tests using CNAuthorizationStatus work fine?

After some tinkering, I found the issue. Answer below.

The issue was how I was executing the test in Xcode.

Pressing the play button next to the @Test annotation runs the test with a single argument.

Pressing the play button next to the @Suite annotation runs the test with all arguments. Unfortunately, this also run all tests in the suite.
